# How to find the network interface transmit performance?

Tags: python, linux

I am checking the number of bytes sent by the interface using the python code.

```
>>> test = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
>>> test['en1'].bytes_sent
```

However, I have one simple question like what's going to happen when the counter overflows - like what is the maximum limit the interface can tell.
I see that the interface counter keeps incrementing. What's the limit of those counters? When shall I see the counter overflow or rollover? Where can I see those limits? I am using Ubuntu machine or mac OSX to run this program?

I have re-run this program and I have seen that the number of bytes sent keeps incrementing but I don't know when it rollover.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, [the underlying `tx_bytes`/`rx_bytes` counters](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/582549e3fbe137eb6ce9be591aca25c2222a36b4/include/linux/netdevice.h#L2396-L2409) are apparently unsigned 64-bit counters, so they range from 0 to a lofty 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes (or about 18,446,744 terabytes).

I don't think you'll need to worry about overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Also according to the documentation at https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_io_counters the function by default automatically detects wraps and adds the old value, so that the counter doesn't ever decrease. This is done by keeping a cache that persists across function calls (but not across application restarts).